# Can I stop this redirect? formsubmit.co

Tags: html, form-submit, contacts, contact-form

Nice to meet you... I am Suki. I just noticed about Formsubmit.co Also it is a great service! my problem is, in my email field if someone enters something like `email@email` with that `.com` it takes it to another page. Where it says to enter a valid email. I don't want something like this... How can I disable it? Or is it possible to redirect it to any page in my domain? like `mydomain.com/error.html`?

Or is it possible to show errors in my page? Like with `AJAX`? or something like that? I have no experience with it. Can someone help me with it? I want everything under my domain . lol

You can also contact me on Discord:- `SukiNotSUS#5538` (send a friend request)

Visit my website for live details:- https://suki.is-a.dev (In the sign up email feild, enter something without a tld eg. blablabla@blablabla)

Thanks in advance,
Suki.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with JQuery by adding a click listener to your submit button that triggers an AJAX call to formsubmit.co. Just replace the content in the `data` JSON of the ajax call with your form data:

```
$(yourButtonSelector).click(function() {
 $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://formsubmit.co/ajax/your@email.com',
    dataType: 'json',
    accepts: 'application/json',
    data: {
        name: "insert name from form here",
        message: "insert message from form here"
    },
    success: (data) => console.log(data),
    error: (err) => console.log(err)
 });
});
```

Click here for more information about AJAX calls to formsubmit.co: https://formsubmit.co/ajax-documentation

If you add the code of your form to your question I can adjust my example to your case

Comment: its working! Thanks :)